# Unable to get jQuery to create proper HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating an accordion menu using json data parsed via jQuery.  The data is imported and displays as it should.  However the HTML that is being created is incorrect, and I'm not sure what the issue is.  Here is the HTML I need to create via jQuery:

```
<div id="pselector">
<div class="accordion accordion-bg clearfix">
    <div class="acctitle" >Category 1</div>
    <div class="acc_content clearfix">Product1</div>

    <div class="acctitle">Category 2</div>
    <div class="acc_content clearfix">Product 2</div>

    <div class="acctitle">Category 3</div>
    <div class="acc_content clearfix">Product 3</div>

    <div class="acctitle">Category 4</div>
    <div class="acc_content clearfix">Product 4</div>

    <div class="acctitle">Category 5</div>
    <div class="acc_content clearfix">Product 5</div>

    <div class="acctitle">Category 6</div>
    <div class="acc_content clearfix">Product 6</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is my current jQuery script:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/products/GetProductList/', function(data) {
        var output = '<div class="accordion accordion-bg clearfix">';
        for (var i in data.Categories) {
            output += '<div class="acctitle">' + data.Categories[i].Category + "</div>";
            output += '<div class="acc_content clearfix">';
            for (var j in data.Categories[i].Products) {
                output += data.Categories[i].Products[j].short_description + " -- " + data.Categories[i].Products[j].cost + " USD";
            }
            output += "</div>";
        }
        output += "</div>";

        document.getElementById("pselector").innerHTML = output;
    });
</script>
```

When I look at the created HTML it appears correct, but doesn't display properly in the browser.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: you can't have LIs in a DIV

Comment: To better word the comment above, `<li>` tags must be used inside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

Comment: I removed the <li> tags, as they weren't the issue.  The problem is that the script isn't creating the HTML correctly.  It looks as though it should, so I'm  confused.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I see here is that you're trying to put `<li>` elements inside of a `<div>`. The div that has the class **acc_content** should be either a `<ul>` (unordered list) or an `<ol>` (ordered list) but `<ul>` is probably what you want. Try this

```
   $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/products/GetProductList/', function(data) {
        var output = '<div class="accordion accordion-bg clearfix">';
        for (var i in data.Categories) {
            output += '<div class="acctitle">' + data.Categories[i].Category + "</div>";
            output += '<ul class="acc_content clearfix">';
            for (var j in data.Categories[i].Products) {
                output += '<li>' + data.Categories[i].Products[j].short_description + " -- " + data.Categories[i].Products[j].cost + " USD  </li>";
            }
            output += "</ul>";
        }
        output += "</div>";

        document.getElementById("pselector").innerHTML = output;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1st I would recommend using a template instead of building the html "by hand" like you are doing.

2nd If you are using jQuery, there's no need to do this:

```
document.getElementById("pselector").innerHTML = output;
```

just do this:

```
$("#pselector").html(output);
```

3rd Can you post the output of said jQuery code?  It would be helpful in determining what went wrong.

Comment: Agree with you: stackoverflow should have the demo mandatory to post a question, to avoid future answer and comment like - post a demo or fiddle - to make comprehensible the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comment above, you CAN have LIs in a DIV. The problem is that you have LIs and no UL or OL tag. It won't render LI without that.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the original question, leave a comment instead.

Comment: LOL it actually IS an answer to the original question which was "When I look at the created HTML it appears correct, but doesn't display properly in the browser. What am I overlooking?" and what he is overlooking is the UL tag (or OL tag if so desired).

Comment: The <li> tag isn't the issue.  Although that may be incorrect also.  The issue is that the script isn't exactly creating the HTML as shown above.  There's something wrong about it, but I can't determine what.  If it created that HTML, it would work.